# Adding a MouseAdapter to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

I has a MouseAdapter that I use to drag a window around simply by clicking its background, like so:

```
public class Dragger extends MouseAdapter{

private Point offset;
private Window window;

public Dragger(Window w){
    window = w;
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    offset = e.getPoint();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

    Point m = e.getLocationOnScreen();

    window.setLocation(m.x - offset.x, m.y - offset.y);
}
}
```

Simple as, right?

And I add it to the JFrame I'm using it on (I'm using it on a JDialogUE as well, hence the 'Window':

```
// Drag Listeners

    Dragger dr = new Dragger(this);
    addMouseListener(dr);
    addMouseMotionListener(dr);
```

The drag (currently) only works when I construct a new Dragger, then add it as **both** a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener.

Is there a nicer, prettier, more elegant, more traditionally sound, more professionally robust, so it goes, way of doing it in just one method?

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I would suggest writing helper static methods within the `Dragger` class:

```
public class Dragger extends MouseAdapter
{
    private Point offset;
    private Window window;

    public Dragger ( final Window w )
    {
        window = w;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed ( final MouseEvent e )
    {
        offset = e.getPoint ();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged ( final MouseEvent e )
    {
        final Point m = e.getLocationOnScreen ();
        window.setLocation ( m.x - offset.x, m.y - offset.y );
    }

    public static void install ( final Window window )
    {
        final Dragger dr = new Dragger ( window );
        window.addMouseListener ( dr );
        window.addMouseMotionListener ( dr );
    }

    public static void uninstall ( final Window window )
    {
        for ( final MouseListener mouseListener : window.getMouseListeners () )
        {
            if ( mouseListener instanceof Dragger )
            {
                window.removeMouseListener ( mouseListener );
            }
        }
        for ( final MouseMotionListener mouseMotionListener : window.getMouseMotionListeners () )
        {
            if ( mouseMotionListener instanceof Dragger )
            {
                window.removeMouseMotionListener ( mouseMotionListener );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then simply call `Dragger.install(window)` and `Dragger.uninstall(window)`.

Not sure whether it is a good approach or not, but it takes less space and might also ensure that you don't add Dragger twice if you add some more checks into `install` method - of course if you don't want to have `Dragger` installed twice on the same window.

Also in that case you don't need to look in your code for the usage of this class since you are sure how it will be installed and uninstalled and can change that behavior in one place instead of modifying lots of `add*Listener` calls.